# Cakephp how can I map and merge two object?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two object `coins` and `user_summarry`

```
$coins = $this->coins->find('all')

$user_summarry = $this->UserSummary->find('all')
```

If I use `toArray()` for coins it's look likes

```
[
   (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Coin) id:0 {
      'id' => (int) 1
      'name' => 'A'
    }
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Coin) id:0 {
      'id' => (int) 2
      'name' => 'B'
    }
  ....
]
```

`toArray()` for `user_summarry`

```
[
   (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\UserSummary) id:0 {
        'id' => (int) 1
        'coin_id' => '2'
        'total' => 120

   }
   ...
]
```

How can I change my coins object like

```
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Coin) id:0 {
      'id' => (int) 1
      'name' => 'A',
      'total' => 0
}
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Coin) id:0 {
      'id' => (int) 2
      'name' => 'B',
      'total' => 120

}
```

After change in array by using 2 foreach loop I am able to change it as an array. How can I use cakephp method to map and concatenate as an object ?

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip:

**CoinsTable:**

```
$this->hasOne('UserSummary',[
   'foreignKey' => 'UserSummary.coin_id',
];
```

**In your Controller:**

```
$results = $this->Coins->find()
   ->contain(['UserSummary'])
   ->select(['id' => 'Coins.id', 'name' => 'Coins.name', 'total' => 'UserSummary.total'])
   ->toArray();

debug($results);
```

Comment: I have given an example here , In my case I have to do it in object matching.

Comment: @NiloyRony The example that you've given doesn't warrant PHP level merging, hence it attracts answers like this (which are technically correct). You may want to update your question with an example that outlines the technical necessity of merging on PHP level, or just make it about the generic task of merging arrays/collections.